# Using Firebase Cloud Functions to fetch data from an external API (Timeout)

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions, axios

This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

exports.apistatus = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method !== "GET") {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Not allowed"
      });
    }

    return axios.get('https://api.bsmsa.eu/ext/api/bsm/gbfs/v2/en/station_status')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return res.status(200).json(
          response.data
        )
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        })
      })

  })
  // ! res.end();
});
```

I'm already using the Blaze Plan but I always get this when I invoke it >> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'.

If I try to terminate the function like the documentation says with res.send() or res.end() I get this error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

It works fine when I try to fetch other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `return` keyword before the cors() function call.

```
exports.apistatus = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    return cors(req, res, () => {     // <------ RETURN NEEDED HERE
        if (req.method !== "GET") {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Not allowed"
            });
        }

        return axios.get('https://api.bsmsa.eu/ext/api/bsm/gbfs/v2/en/station_status')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                return res.status(200).json(
                    response.data
                )
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                })
            })

    })
});
```

Your axios code is being executed, and I suspect it's receiving a response, but because you aren't returning the result from CORS, the "parent" cloud function never knows the task has finished.

[This example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js) shows a sample from the official Firebase GitHub where they're using Cors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jeremy! Unfortunately I tried what you suggested but it's still not working, I get the same Timeout error. It's weird because it works with other APIs, maybe the problem is there?

Comment: Yeah, that's very weird. If it works 100% perfectly with all other APIs then it only makes sense for the issue to be on this specific API's side. Unfortunately, unless you control that API & can debug why they don't respond... there's not a lot you can do to fix it. As a quick debugging step - since you're specifying the region in your cloud function... I would double check that you are 100% sure that you're executing the correct version of your function. Throw a `console.log()` before the call to `axios` to make sure it's actually hitting that code. If you see the log, then I'm out of ideas.